# Applying $filter option to retrieve folder with a specific name in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The following filter clause does not work in the Graph Explorer

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives?$filter=name eq 'Documents'

Are there any limitations in the application of filters as the specified filter is as per OData protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive API (and Graph API on drives) do not support filtering or ordering results.
When Microsoft Graph sees a query parameter it doesn't expect, it simply ignoring the unknown filter parameter and returning us an unfiltered result.
The [drives api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/drive_list) supports the $expand, $select, $skipToken, $top, and $orderby(orderby does not work on my side) OData query parameters to customize the response.

My test data:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives?$filter=name eq 'Documents'/$filter=driveType eq 'documentLibrary'":

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2018-06-04T07:32:28Z",
            "description": "List of all app packages uploaded in the Dev Site",
            "id": "b!NEuoD0E0IkyGzigmyNtKyXtJFUgDWoBJhM2BFIAvNsp69o2q1-czTaV6INjgi_dk",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-06-05T04:19:59Z",
            "name": "App Packages",
            "webUrl": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/Lists/AppPackages",
            "driveType": "documentLibrary",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "System Account"
                }
            },
            "quota": {
                "deleted": 0,
                "remaining": 0,
                "total": 0,
                "used": 0
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: The currently available documentation https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter just states "Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs." The word varies might be the inference that these options are not totally supported across all products.

Comment: Yeah, based on our test it have not fully support all products now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems with the newer version you can use FileName or FileType search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide#searchable-site-properties

```
{"requests":[{"entityTypes":["microsoft.graph.driveItem"],"query":{"query_string":{"query":"fileextension:xlsx"}},"from":0,"size":25}]}
```